# SSH into another machine and run robot framework tests

Tags: bash, ssh, robotframework

I can run tests on remote machine as `pybot test.robot`. Now I want to ssh into remote machine from local machine and run above command. I can ssh into remote machine as `ssh user@10.0.0.200 ls` and see files.

But when I try to run command `ssh user@10.0.0.200 pybot ~/dir/test.robot` I get error `bash: pybot: command not found`

`pybot` is installed on remote machine I can run tests successfully if I run them directly from remote machine.

Comment: Have you tried to use the complete path for pybot on the remote node?

Comment: @jyvet yes! adding full path worked but now I'm getting error for other import libraries. Do I need to specify any specific `pythonpath`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to export your `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at the top of your *.bashrc* config file. For instance:

```
export PATH=path-to-the-pybot-directory:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path-to-lib-directory-for-pybot:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

You may use `ldd pybot` to locate where libraries requiered by pybot are installed.